# join SQL query problem

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have following query which returns the product and the lowest sell price found with the quantity of that sell price. Everything works perfectly until I want to get a product that does not have any prices in the product_price table. How can I let return it the product data and NULLS for sellPrice and quantity?

```
SELECT p.*, MIN(pp.sellPrice) as sellPrice, pp.quantity FROM `product` as p
LEFT JOIN `product_price_group` as ppg ON ppg.productId = p.`id`
LEFT JOIN `product_price` as pp ON pp.priceGroupId = ppg.`id`
WHERE p.`id` = 1 AND p.`active` = 1
```

**Output of an product that has a price available:**

```
+----+--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| id | name         | active | sortSequence | creationDate | sellPrice | quantity |
+----+--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | product_id_1 |      1 |            1 |   1287481220 |     22.00 |       10 |
+----+--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

**Output of an product that does not have a pricing avaialble**

```
+----+------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| id | name | active | sortSequence | creationDate | sellPrice | quantity |
+----+------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| NULL | NULL | NULL |         NULL |         NULL |      NULL |     NULL |
+----+------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

**Desired output:**

```
+----+--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| id | name         | active | sortSequence | creationDate | sellPrice | quantity |
+----+--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
|  2 | product_id_2 |      1 |            1 |   1287481220 |     NULL  |     NULL |
+----+--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

**Update** 
It seems that I was selecting oN product items that don't exist! Very stupid.

Comment: MySQL *and* TSQL tags? I mean, you don't have a `GROUP BY` clause so it's MySQL but did you have to tag it with TSQL?

Comment: Got a bit of an optical illusion going on there with the table. Do the lines look bent to anyone? ;-D

Comment: I created a best-guess version of a minimal schema for the tables and data in MySql, and when I execute the queries I get what I would expect (and what you desire to see), so obviously I made an incorrect guess as to the appropriate schema for one or more of the tables (or the data therein). Can you provide some guidance on the schema, relationships ad data you're looking at?

Comment: Also perhaps the output of a DESCRIBE [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html] of each query, which might give us a clue to where your joins are failing to find rows.

Comment: I already found the problem see the update.

Answer (score 0):

What about using LEFT OUTER JOIN for product_price table?

```
SELECT p.*, MIN(pp.sellPrice) as sellPrice, pp.quantity FROM `product` as p
LEFT JOIN `product_price_group` as ppg ON ppg.productId = p.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_price` as pp ON pp.priceGroupId = ppg.`id`
WHERE p.`id` = 1 AND p.`active` = 1
```

Is this what you want?

UPDATE: Revision - Like others say, `LEFT JOIN = LEFT (OUTER) JOIN` so it will not help you in this case...

Comment: I believe the OUTER is optional - LEFT JOIN assumes OUTER.

Comment: agree. LEFT OUTER JOIN = LEFT JOIN, and INNER JOIN = JOIN

Answer (score 0):

I MAY be incorrect, but my understanding of a LEFT JOIN has always been the table reference in the equality test as written in the SQL statement... which is in addition, how I write queries... Start with the table I'm expecting FIRST (left), joined to the OTHER (right) table second...  Keep the join condition ALSO respective of that relationship...

```
select from x left join y where x.fld = y.fld
   instead of 
select from x left join y where y.fld = x.fld
```

So I would adjust your query as follows

```
SELECT
      p.*, 
      MIN(pp.sellPrice) as sellPrice, 
      pp.quantity 
   FROM 
      product as p
         LEFT JOIN product_price_group as ppg 
            ON p.id = ppg.productId
            LEFT JOIN product_price as pp 
               ON ppg.id = pp.priceGroupId
   WHERE 
          p.id = 1 
      AND p.active = 1
```

Additionally, you can wrap your min() and quantity with a IFNULL( field, 0 ) to prevent NULLS from showing but instead have actual zero values.

Comment: Unfortunately it makes no difference